# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nrows'

Tags: python, xlsx, xlrd

I'm going to use `nrows` for my xlsx file but I get this error:
`NoneType' object has no attribute 'nrows'`

Yesterday, it was working but when I rewrote my program this error showed up.

My code is:

```py
import xlrd
def read_excel_files(loc):
    file=xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
    sheet=file.sheet_by_index(0)
    
sheet=read_excel_files("C:/Users/****/Desktop/DataSet.xlsx")
dataset=[]
    
for i in range(0 , sheet.nrows):
    temp_list=[sheet.cell.value(i , 0), sheet.cell.value(i , 0)]
    dataset.append(temp_list)
    print(dataset)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as William said that returning the variable `sheet` will solve the problem, here is your modified code:

```py
import xlrd
def read_excel_files(loc):
    file=xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
    sheet=file.sheet_by_index(0)
    return sheet

sheet=read_excel_files("C:/Users/****/Desktop/DataSet.xlsx")
dataset=[]

for i in range(0 , sheet.nrows):
    temp_list=[sheet.cell.value(i , 0), sheet.cell.value(i , 0)]
    dataset.append(temp_list)
    print(dataset)
```

Answer (score 0):

`read_excel_files()` returns value `None`, because it doesn't have a return statement. Adding `return sheet` to that function will solve your issues